# call/CC with closures

Tags: javascript, callcc

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) mentions that "In any language which supports closures and proper tail calls, it is possible to write programs in continuation-passing style and manually implement call/cc."

How would one implement this function in for example in javascript? I know that javascript doesn't do tco, but assuming that stack space doesn't run out

Comment: Check out [jwacs](http://chumsley.org/jwacs/), and [this](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/cps/) for a simple mechanism.

Comment: The second example explains continuations and that you could implement exceptions with call/cc, but doesn't go into implementing call/cc. The first example has missing documentation (at least on first look), and deciphering the source is a bit of an overkill :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to write a call/cc implementation in JavaScript:

JavaScript does not meet the requirement of "proper tail calls" (no additional stack creation). However, I believe that a *form* of continuations, such as that found in Jetty, using exceptions is possible. "CPS" is as easy as passing a function-object, although ultimately it runs into stack issues as well unless backed out occasionally.

Happy coding.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in JS by (occasionally) clearing the stack using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @StevenLu "Sort of". That is what I was hinting at with "unless backed out occasionally" -- perhaps catching the overflow exception? Although I am not sure how the implementation would be flushed out ..

Comment: Yes. For me, I can't see any reason to justify writing JS in CPS unless the task is heavily asynchronous and requires or greatly benefits from storing or passing continuation functions to be run at a later time: If that isn't the case or if performance is important, a regular recursive or iterative implementation is likely more appropriate. This should mean that the short delays caused by setTimeout (to unwind the stack) will be tolerable. As for bringing exceptions into the mix... sounds a little scary.

Comment: function callcc (f,cc) { 
  f(function(x,k) { cc(x) },cc)
}    As shown in http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/

Comment: I've also seen people do a Cheney-on-the-MTA approach, using sugar.js to create thunks of every step and upon a stack overflow starting over with a new stack.  It's rather slow, but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

**synchronous call/cc**

Other approaches use `setTimeout` or Promise and forces the caller to deal with asynchrony. Synchronous `callcc` can be implemented with `try-catch`. Let's first see the naive approach -

```js
// naive
const callcc = f => {
  try { return f(value => { throw value }) }
  catch (e) { return e }
}

console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * 3))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * exit(3)))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); return 3 }))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { throw Error("oh no!") }))
```

```
35             ✅ 5 + 10 * 3
8              ✅ 5 + 3
15             ✅ 5 + 10
5Error: oh no! ❌ the thrown Error was treated as a return value
```

Wups! If we use `throw` for the continuation's return, how does `catch` know whether we called the continuation or a real error occurred? The important bit is that the continuation must "box" the return value and "unbox" it in `catch` to avoid swallowing real errors -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  class Box { constructor(v) { this.unbox = v } }
  try { return f(value => { throw new Box(value) }) }
  catch (e) { if (e instanceof Box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * 3))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * exit(3)))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); return 3 }))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); throw Error("test failed") }))

try {
  console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { throw Error("test passed!") }))
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
35                     ✅ 5 + 10 * 3
8                      ✅ 5 + 3
15                     ✅ 5 + 10
15                     ✅ 5 + 10
Error: test passed!    ✅ Errors are not swallowed
```

**short circuit**

Given a list of numbers, let's multiply all of them. As humans we know if a single 0 is present, the product must be 0. `callcc` allows us to encode that same short-circuiting behavior. In the demo below `mult(a,b)` is used so we can see when actual work is happening. In a real program it could be replaced with `a * b` -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  class Box { constructor(v) { this.unbox = v } }
  try { return f(value => { throw new Box(value) }) }
  catch (e) { if (e instanceof Box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

const apply = (x, f) => f(x)

const mult = (a, b) => {
  console.log("multiplying", a, b)
  return a * b
}

console.log("== without callcc ==")
console.log(
  apply([1,2,3,0,4], function recur(a) {
    if (a.length == 0) return 1
    return mult(a[0], recur(a.slice(1)))
  })
)

console.log("== with callcc ==")
console.log(
  callcc(exit =>
    apply([1,2,3,0,4], function recur(a) {
      if (a.length == 0) return 1
      if (a[0] == 0) exit(0) // 
      return mult(a[0], recur(a.slice(1)))
    })
  )
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== without callcc ==
multiplying 4 1
multiplying 0 4  here we know the answer must be zero but recursion continues
multiplying 3 0
multiplying 2 0
multiplying 1 0
0
== with callcc ==
0  the answer is calculated without performing any unnecessary work
```

**other implementations**

Here we trade the `Box` class for a lightweight Symbol -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  try { return f(unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * 3))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * exit(3)))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); return 3 }))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); throw Error("test failed") }))

try {
  console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { throw Error("test passed!") }))
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

```
35                     ✅ 5 + 10 * 3
8                      ✅ 5 + 3
15                     ✅ 5 + 10
15                     ✅ 5 + 10
Error: test passed!    ✅ Errors are not swallowed
```

**caveat**

In languages that support first-class continuations, you can return the continuation itself and call it at a later time. In JavaScript we cannot support this as the continuation is no longer run in the `try-catch` context. If you want to prevent the caller from misusing the continuation in this way, we can throw a specific error -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  const exit = unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }
  try {
    const result = f(exit)
    if (result === exit) throw Error("cannot return unbounded continuation")
    return result
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox;
    throw e 
  }
}

console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * 3))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => 10 * exit(3)))
console.log(5 + callcc(exit => { exit(10); return 3 }))

try {
  const cc = callcc(exit => exit) // ⚠️ returns continuation
  cc("hello world") // ⚠️ calls continuation out of context
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
35                                            ✅ 
8                                             ✅ 
15                                            ✅ 
Error: cannot return unbounded continuation!  ✅
```

**remarks**

Transplanting features from one language to another is not strictly forbidden but I don't recommend this as a common practice. `callcc` is a utility that exists in other languages that are written to support goals a feature set that differs from JavaScript. JavaScript supports a wide variety of tools and patterns that are best for supporting JavaScript programs. Whatever you are trying to do with `callcc` probably has an appropriate JavaScript idiom you should be using instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14019341/783743). This is how you would implement it:

```
Function.prototype.async = async;

function async() {
    setTimeout.bind(null, this, 0).apply(null, arguments);
}

function callcc(f, cc) {
    f.async(cc);
}
```

Then you may use it as follows:

```
pythagoras.async(3, 4, alert);

function pythagoras(x, y, cont) {
    callcc.async(square.bind(null, x), function cc(x_squared) {
        callcc.async(square.bind(null, y), function cc(y_squared) {
            add.async(x_squared, y_squared, cont);
        });
    });
}

function square(x, cont) {
    multiply.async(x, x, cont);
}

function multiply(x, y, cont) {
    cont.async(x * y);
}

function add(x, y, cont) {
    cont.async(x + y);
}
```

You may fiddle with the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/brZrd/

Comment: @DestinyArchitect Duplication is not a bad thing. One of the creators of StackOverflow, Jeff Atwood, is in favor of duplication: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/. Now, my answer is indeed a copy of an earlier answer. However, it's not pointless because a) it's a summary of the main points of the earlier answer with a link for a more detailed explanation b) it addresses the OP's problem and is a whole answer by itself. If I'd just linked to my previous answer without summarizing then it wouldn't really be an answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible

https://github.com/zaoqi/callcc.js/blob/master/callcc.js

```
async function callcc(f){
  return await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    const resolve_packed=(v)=>{
      resolve(v)
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{})
    }
    f(resolve_packed).then(resolve).catch(reject)
  })
}
```

use it:

```
test('test1',()=>{
  expect.assertions(1)
  expect((()=>{
    async function q(k,v){
      console.log('testing1')
      await k(v)
    }
    return callcc(async function(k){
      console.log('testing0')
      await q(k,133)
      console.error('test error')
    })
  })()).resolves.toBe(133)
})
```