# Javascript Variable Not Changed Outside of Function Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, zope

I have the following function:

```
function loginStudent() {
    var advisorKEY = "<dtml-var expr="py_get_alias()">";
    var studentKEY = "<dtml-var SID>";  
    var URL = "py_logging_sessionOpen?AdvisorKEY=" + advisorKEY + "&StudentKEY=" + studentKEY;
    key = "";
    $j.get(URL, function(data) { 
        key = data;
    });
    alert(key);
}
```

The `py_loggin_sessionOpen` is just a python script running on my server.
It returns a single string.  I need the response of that script to determine the next action. The script returns the value perfectly, and I can easily check the value by putting an `alert` within the `function(data)` in `get`.

**My main question is:** how to get the key value to be changed outside the scope of function(data)?

I assumed because I defined it externally it would act as a global variable.
Moving it outside `loginStudent()` does not solve the problem either.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to use it in another function?

Comment: All logic which depends on the result of an asynchronous request must be dealt with in the callback function of the request. `alert(key)` is being called before the value of `key` is set by the async. function.

Answer (score 6):

`$j.get()` is going to be an asynchronous call. That means it fires, and the rest of the execution continues. Anything that relies on that call needs to be done in the callback, like so:

```
$j.get(URL, function(data) { 
    key = data;
    alert(key);
} );
```

If everything else is good, you'll see the value you expect.

Comment: Ah! Duh. Thanks.  I'll accept your answer when StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `$j.get` executes asynchronously. That's the reason you pass a callback to it.

If you wish to write asynchronous code synchronously then you should read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809354/783743

**Edit:** It seems that you have created a global variable called `key` by not declaring it with `var`. Hence it should be visible in other functions as long as they are called **after** the callback.

Would you care to provide us these other functions?