# Why do no javascript engines support tail call optimization?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I recently learned about tail call optimization in Haskell. I've learned from the following posts that this is not a feature of javascript:

- [Tail Recursion optimization for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498939/tail-recursion-optimization-for-javascript)
- [Are any Javascript engines tail call optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660577/are-any-javascript-engines-tail-call-optimized)

Is there something inherent to javascript's design that makes tail call optimization especially difficult? Why is this a main feature of a language like haskell, but is only now being discussed as a feature of certain javascript engines?

Comment: I think ES6 will provide it.

Comment: Yep, I believe you're correct. I was more wondering **why** it is the case that it has only **now** been added as a feature?

Comment: See [this article](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/tail-calls-optimization-es6/) explaining the difficulties in tail-call optimization. And yes, it will be implemented for sure in ES6.

Comment: The vast difference is that TCO is *necessary* in haskell, while it is just a *feature* in other languages that adds complexity to the compiler.

Comment: In addition, massive recursion will also encounter call stack limitation which is very small by default. I think JS (as of ES5) is not primarily aimed for recursion in the past.

Comment: @Bergi One might argue that because of the ackermann function's existence, all languages need tail recursion.

Comment: @AJFarmar: How would TCO help with computing the ackermann function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tail call optimisation is supported in JavaScript. No browsers implement it yet but it's coming as the specification (ES2015) is finalized and all environments *will have* to implement it. Transpilers like BabelJS that translate new JavaScript to old JavaScript already support it and you can use it today.

The translation Babel makes is pretty simple:

```
function tcoMe(x){
    if(x === 0) return x;
    return tcoMe(x-1)
}
```

Is converted to:

```
function tcoMe(_x) {
    var _again = true;

    _function: while (_again) {
        var x = _x;
        _again = false;

        if (x === 0) return x;
        _x = x - 1;
        _again = true;
        continue _function;
    }
}
```

That is - to a while loop.

As for why it's only *newly* supported, there wasn't a big *need* from the community to do so sooner since it's an imperative language with loops so for the vast majority of cases you can write this optimization yourself (unlike in MLs where this is required, as Bergi pointed out).

Comment: You don't mean Machine Languagues, do you?

Comment: @Bergi hehe, no, I meant [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)s, which is a family of languages like OCaml and F# (direct dialects) and Haskell (ML with non-strict evaluation but same idea), although the statement is equally true for other functional languages like scheme.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected, but the plural confused me. I've never referred to ML as a *family* of language*s* :-)

Comment: A Tail call can reuse the stack frame of its enclosing function (same return point). Only the internal vars including arguments have to be initialized. Does that mean, tail calls are similarly well optimizable for JS engines as imperative loops? Usually I don't care about micro optimization, but when it comes to iterations...

Comment: @IvenMarquardt yes, potentially tail calls are _as_ fast.

Comment: 2019 and still practically no support implemented in web browsers - https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: It was removed from the language

Comment: In other posts some Chrome team dev explained why Chrome "unshipped" TCE/TCO and basically TCE/TCO is really dead because browser vendor disagree on the semantics that it should have etc. It will probably be removed from the standard or in the next one.

Comment: See my extensive recap of the history in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719548/tail-call-optimization-implementation-in-javascript-engines/54721813#54721813).