# Tail Call Optimization implementation in Javascript Engines

Tags: javascript, firefox, chromium, v8

As of February 2019 in Chrome Version `71.0.3578.98` on Mac
, the following program throws  `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error.` at a count of `16516`.

```
const a = x => {
  console.log(x)
  a(x + 1)
}

a(1)
```

I've done quite a bit of Googling, but wasn't able to find any articles discussing Chrome or other browser support for Tail Call Optimization (TCO) or any future plans to implement it.

My two questions are:

1. Is TCO currently supported in Chrome or any other browser or Javascript Engine
2. Are there plans to implement TCO in the near future in any Javascript Engine

The posts that I've found are mostly old (2016 or earlier) or simply confusing. e.g. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5516876633341952

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_%28tail_call_optimisation%29

Answer (score 89, accepted):

TCO, or rather, Tail Call *Elimination* in JavaScript -- also often referred to as Proper Tail Calls (PTC) in discussions -- is a long and sad story.

Around 2011, TC39 (the JavaScript standards committee) decided to adopt mandatory TCE for the forthcoming ES6 standard, with consensus from all major browser vendors.

In 2015, the new standard was officially adopted, under the name EcmaScript 2015. At this point, no browser had actually implemented TCE, mostly because there were too many new features in ES2015 that were deemed more important to get out. (Today's process for JS feature proposals and their adoption, which includes the requirement of two implementations in production engines, did not yet exist for ES6.)

In early 2016, both Safari and Chrome implemented TCE. Safari announced shipping it, while Chrome kept it behind an Experimental Feature flag. Other browsers (Firefox and Internet Explorer / Edge) started looking into it as well and had second thoughts. Discussion evolved whether this is a viable feature after all. Edge had problems implementing it efficiently for the Windows ABI, Firefox was concerned about the developer experience of calls "missing" from stack traces (an issue that was already discussed at length in 2011).

In an attempt to address some of these concerns while rescuing the tail call feature, several members, including the Chrome and Edge teams, proposed to make tail calls *explicit*, i.e., require return statements to be annotated with an additional keyword to opt into tail call semantics. These so-called "[syntactic tail calls](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-ptc-syntax)" (STC) were implemented in Chrome as a proof of concept.

At the May 2016 TC39 meeting the issue of tail calls was discussed extensively for almost an entire day with no resolution. Firefox and Edge made clear that they would not implement TCE as specified in the standard. Firefox members proposed to take it out. Safari and Chrome did not agree with that, and the Safari team made clear that they have no intention of unshipping TCE. The proposal for syntactic tail calls was rejected as well, especially by Safari. The committee was in an impasse. You can read the [meeting notes of this discussion](https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/main/meetings/2016-05/may-24.md#syntactic-tail-calls-bt).

Technically, this impasse still exists today, as far as I am aware. Practically speaking, though, tail calls for JavaScript are pretty much dead, and it's unclear whether they will ever come back. At least that was the conclusion of the Chrome team after the disastrous meeting, which led to the decision to remove the implementation of tail calls from Chrome, in order to simplify the engine and prevent bit rot. They are still available in Safari.

Disclosure: I was a member of TC39 and of the Chrome/V8 team until 2017, so my views may be biased.

Comment: Nice answer! You might want to re-post it at [ES6 Tail Recursion Optimisation Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42788139/1048572) or [Why do no javascript engines support tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31273281/1048572) - I consider closing this as a duplicate then

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: (Sadly) very illustrative answer. Just for future reference, it is worth mentioning that there is a thoroughly tested library https://github.com/glathoud/fext that may be a good alternative to patterns like trampoline

Comment: Douglas Crockford says Microsoft sabotaged TCO because they couldn't implement it properly in their CLR (I heard him talk about this on a 2019-09 podcast).  He still maintains some hope that it isn't dead.

Comment: @Tom, I wouldn't say sabotage, but in the end it was both Microsoft and Mozilla who made clear that they don't want to implement them, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The "Syntactic tail calls" would have been a great addition - any language that supports PTC would benefit from having some syntactic way to mark the developer's intention of using tail call recursion, to help future maintainers to not accidentally refactor out the optimization.

Comment: At least Microsoft's reason was technical, as dumb as it is. Firefox's makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 29):

Even tho TCO seems to be a pipe dream for all of us, by using a `trampoline` technique, you can easily convert your code to run as if it is being tail optimized.

```js
const a = x => {
  if(x > 500000) {
      console.log(x);
      return; 
  }
  return ()=> a(x + 1); //you return a function, it hasn't been called yet
}

const trampoline = fn => (...args) => {
  let result = fn(...args)
  //repeatedly call the function till you hit your base case
  while (typeof result === 'function') {
    result = result();
  }
  
  return result;
}

var t = trampoline(a);
t(1);
```

Comment: That's very clever, but it only works for functions that call *themselves*, not other functions, in the tail position.

Comment: @RonInbar You _can_ call other functions using the same technique, but the return value of those functions should _also_ use the inline function syntax shown above.