# Does Google Apps Script (GAS) support proper tail calls or tail call optimization?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8

I'm wondering whether investing time into doing [tail call optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?TailCallOptimization) for a Google Apps Script is worth it.

So, I've understood that Google Apps Script uses the ES2015 (ES6) version of the JavaScript specification ([ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript?hl=en), [ref2](https://www.labnol.org/es6-google-apps-script-v8-200206)), running it [on the V8 runtime implementation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

Supposedly, [ES2015 supports](http://bdadam.com/blog/video-douglas-crockford-about-the-new-good-parts.html) (proper) tail call optimization from the spec. But there are [some indications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Language_support) that V8 actually doesn't implement it:

- [What happened to proper tail calls in JavaScript?](https://world.hey.com/mgmarlow/what-happened-to-proper-tail-calls-in-javascript-5494c256)
- [Tail Call Optimization implementation in Javascript Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54721813/380607)

Furthermore, I've learned there is an important nuance here:

> The terminology of proper tail calls (PTC) and tail call optimization (TCO) is often conflated. Here's the difference between the two:
>
> - **proper tail calls:** functions called in the tail position reuse the current stack frame, preventing the creation of additional stack frames that cause space inefficiency.
> - **tail call optimization:** rewrites a recursive function into an iterative one, usually by calling goto.
>
> PTC only deals with stack manipulation, while TCO rewrites a recursive
> function as an iterative function.

So, given this...

***Does Google Apps Script (GAS):***

- ***support proper tail calls?*** My guess from the above is "No.", but it'd be nice to have an authoritative answer, as far as possible.
- ***support tail call optimization to the point where it is worth doing it, for performance, in any way?*** My guess is "Yes, you can do it, but it doesn't improve performance." But it'd be nice if someone knew it definitively, or could point to a GAS performance comparison that demonstrates it.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed about V8 not implementing it

Comment: This seems like a question for GAS developers/support, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> Does Google Apps Script (GAS) support proper tail calls?

No. V8 does not support PTCs (nor STCs); you've already [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54721813/6036428) to the background story yourself. Since GAS is built on V8 for JS execution, it can't support them either.

> wondering whether investing time into doing tail call optimization for a script is worth it. / Does GAS support tail call optimization to the point where it is worth doing it, for performance, in any way?

I'm not sure what you mean: TCO is something that a compiler potentially does, not something you do.

If you mean "moving calls into tail positions, so the compiler can turn them into iterations": No, V8 doesn't do that, so that's not worth your time. Whether a call occurs in a tail position or not makes no difference for performance. (And I wouldn't bet on that changing any time soon.)

If you mean "manually converting recursion into iteration": that may be worth doing for performance-critical code; whether it's worth doing in your particular case can only be answered by trying it and measuring the effect. (As always, a small artificial test a.k.a. "microbenchmark"  is very likely to produce misleading results that don't apply to other situations.)
This doesn't need any "support" from GAS or V8.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer and disambiguation! You adressed what I meant by TCO in the second to last paragraph (and the last paragraph was also something related that I wondered about).