# Tail recursion in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm not very experienced in JS. But as most people I sometimes have the need to add some extra functionality to a browser.

When looking for answers to other questions I came upon [this answer at SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop) The answer and [the responder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908/daniel-vassallo) are highly upvoted, and by SO standards it means they are pretty reliable. 
What caught my attention is that in the "neatened up" variation it uses tail recursion to loop the function:

```
(function myLoop (i) {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
      alert('hello');          //  your code here                
      if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
   }, 3000)
})(10);
```

From my perspective this looks like bad engineering. Using recursion to solve non recursive problems in an imperative/OO language is to ask for trouble. Ten or 100 iterations should be safe. But what about 10000 or an infinite loop? 
In purely functional languages as Erlang and Haskell I know that tail recursions are converted to loops during compile time and will not add an extra frame to the stack. That is as far as I know not the case for all compilers of for example C/C++ or Java.

How about JS? Is it safe to use tail recursion there without the risk of an SO? Or will this depend on the actual interpreter the script runs on?

Comment: Most of the votes come from the fact that it's an easily googleable question, not that it's specifically good. The code is bad, they should use `setInterval()` instead.

Comment: The setTimeout is used to call your function x millisecs after the call. It's a common pattern to execute something every x millisecs. In this case, a for loop would need to call all the setTimeout with a known delay fo each one : x * 3000. Don't know if it can result in SO as it's not a real recursion.

Comment: @Hacketo Why do you call this "not a real recursion"? How would you clasify this and why? To me this looks like how I would implement a loop by tail-recursion in for example Erlang.

Comment: @EinarSundgren a `setTimeout` add a function call on the "main" stack of execution, not on the same that called it, so it's not adding stack on the latest one. (I don't know Erlang, for examples)

Comment: @Hacketo So it is actually because of the properties of the function used? If it were to be any other, for example 'setIntervall()' as  suggested, the answer would be different? As I said, I'm a JS dabbler trying to hone my skills a bit.

Comment: @EinarSundgren `setInterval` is the same, it will try to add your function call on an execution stack every x ms, so an SO is might not be possible. A "real" recursion code is like georg answer

Comment: @EinarSundgren There's no such thing as a "non-recursive" problem, except for those which require very trivial code. Any problem which justifies using a loop also [justifies using a recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Relationship_with_recursion), *for exactly the same reason:* they both express the same mathematical concept of [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The example you provided does not have any tail recursion. Consider:

```js
(function loop(i) {
    setTimeout(function main() {
        alert("Hello World!");
        if (i > 1) loop(i - 1);
    }, 3000);
}(3));
```

1. I've given the inner function the name `main` and the outer function the name `loop`.
2. The `loop` function is immediately invoked with the value `3`.
3. The `loop` function only does one thing. It invokes `setTimeout` and then returns.
4. Hence, the call to `setTimeout` is a tail call.
5. Now, `main` is called by the JavaScript event loop after `3000` milliseconds.
6. When `main` is called both `loop` and `setTimeout` have completed execution.
7. The `main` function conditionally calls `loop` with a decremented value of `i`.
8. When `main` calls `loop`, it is a tail call.
9. However, it doesn't matter whether you recurse 100 times or 10000 times, the stack size will never increase so much to cause an overflow. The reason is that when you use `setTimeout`, the `loop` function immediately returns. Hence, by the time `main` is called `loop` is no longer on the stack.

A visual explanation:

```
|---------------+ loop (i = 3)
                |---------------+ setTimeout (main, 3000)
                                |
                |---------------+ setTimeout return
|---------------+ loop return
~
~ 3000 milliseconds
~
|---------------+ main (i = 3)
                |---------------+ alert ("Hello World!")
                                |
                |---------------+ alert return
                | i > 1 === true
                |---------------+ loop (i = 2)
                                |---------------+ setTimeout (main, 3000)
                                                |
                                |---------------+ setTimeout return
                |---------------+ loop return
|---------------+ main return
~
~ 3000 milliseconds
~
|---------------+ main (i = 2)
                |---------------+ alert ("Hello World!")
                                |
                |---------------+ alert return
                | i > 1 === true
                |---------------+ loop (i = 1)
                                |---------------+ setTimeout (main, 3000)
                                                |
                                |---------------+ setTimeout return
                |---------------+ loop return
|---------------+ main return
~
~ 3000 milliseconds
~
|---------------+ main (i = 1)
                |---------------+ alert ("Hello World!")
                                |
                |---------------+ alert return
                | i > 1 === false
|---------------+ main return
```

Here's what's happening:

1. First, `loop(3)` is called and `3000` milliseconds after it returns `main` is called.
2. The `main` function calls `loop(2)` and `3000` milliseconds after it returns `main` is called again.
3. The `main` function calls `loop(1)` and `3000` milliseconds after it returns `main` is called again.

Hence, the stack size never grows indefinitely because of `setTimeout`.

Read the following question and answer for more details:

[What's the difference between a continuation and a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14019341/783743)

Hope that helps.

P.S. Tail call optimization will be coming to JavaScript in ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) and it's perhaps the most awaited feature on the list.

Comment: nice drawing skills .

Answer (score 5):

That code is not recursive per se, quite the contrary, it uses [continuation passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) to eliminate tail calls. Here's an example without `setTimeout`:

```js
// naive, direct recursion

function sum_naive(n) {
  return n == 0 ? 0 : n + sum_naive(n-1);
}

try {
  sum_naive(50000)
} catch(e) {
  document.write(e + "<br>")
}


// use CPS to optimize tail recursive calls

function sum_smart(n) {
  
  function f(s, n) {
    return n == 0 ? s : function() { return f(s+n, n-1) };
  }
  
  var p = f(0, n)
  
  while(typeof p == "function")
    p = p()
    
  return p;
}

document.write(sum_smart(50000) + "<br>")
```

CPS is commonly used for tail recursion optimization in languages that don't support it out of the box. Javascript's `setTimeout` basically takes the current continuation and "throws" it to the main thread. Once the main thread is ready, it "catches" the continuation and runs the code in the restored context.

Comment: Could you provide more information on how this works? The other ones talk about the event loop, so I gathered some information about what it's doing. On the other hand, I don't really understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a clear recursion. Each call of `myLoop` will be performed on another stack of execution (somewhat like a separate thread) and does not rely on previous calls. As in original answer:

> The setTimeout() function is non-blocking and will return immediately.

There is a `myLoop` function, that launches a timeout and an anonymous function, that handles, what should be performed after that timeout. The value, returned by `myLoop()` (which will be `undefined`) is not used later in the calls.

Comment: "separate thread" , I would say, "on another stack of execution".

Comment: @Hacketo yeah, that's why I've put it in quotes. But I'll edit it, thanks

Comment: I don't know the real name of this thing but Javascript is not multithreaded, your function will be fired only after your last function execution. a setTimeout(..,0) will be called only when the current stack has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, tail recursion is not supported in most JS runtimes. Therefore unless you know exactly which runtime your code will be running, it will not be safe to rely on tail recursion to avoid "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

It is [not supported in Node](https://node.green/#ES2015-optimisation-proper-tail-calls--tail-call-optimisation-) (with the exception of versions >6.4 & <8 where it can be enabled with a flag).

Safari versions 11 and 12 also appear to support it, but [no other major browsers do](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)).

Dr. Axel Rauschmayer has mentioned on his blog [2ality on 2018-05-09](http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) that widespread support may never come.