# How to return from the function which called the current function?

Tags: typescript

Let's say, I've two functions `f1()` and `f2()`. To serve its purpose, `f1()` needs to return a truthy value. `f1()` calls `f2()` and based on conditions, I want `f2()` to either return a truthy value or return directly from `f1()` (the calling function).

```
//f1()
function f1() {
    const a = f2();
    ...
    ...
    return ...
}

//f2()
function f2() {
    ...
    if(error) {
        // I want to execute return on f1()'s scope here
    }
    ...
    return ...
}
```

My Approach:

```
//f2()
function f2(callback: () => void) {
    ...
    if(error) {
        callback();
    }
    ...
    return ...
}

//f1()
function f1() {
    const a = f2(() => {return...});
    ...
    ...
    return ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it's only returning back the values in the `f2()` as expected.

How to solve this issue? Please, don't suggest other things like returning null from `f2()` in `if` block and return in `f1()` based on condition. I want `f2()` to end execution of `f1()` because of my own reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f2` doesn't necessarily know it's being called from `f1`, right? You could refactor someday to have `f1` call `f3` which then calls `f2`. At that point it would be unclear whether you want `f2` to force the return of `f3` or `f1`. In general, languages expect that `f2` is [written not to know exactly where it is being called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine#Main_concepts), or to have deep control over what happens in the calling method: `f2`'s return value should substitute for the call to `f2` without having further control over `f1`'s execution.

The typical ways of solving this problem are to `throw` an exception (which will go up the stack to the point where it is caught, and would be especially reasonable given this seems to be an error case) or to `return` a sentinel value that indicates that you should return early. It sounds like falsy values like `false` or `null` are good candidates, but you've already indicated that this standard approach is unsuitable for your needs.

However, another technique you could use is a [*continuation passing* style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), which I suggest because it seems you're fine to edit `f2` to take a callback (of which a continuation is a [special form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14019341/1426891)). This allows `f1` to delegate control to `f2`, except that it calls the callback on success rather than failure. This is much more common in asynchronous cases like Promises than in your synchronous case, but it might allow for the flexibility you need in the synchronous case, and it does allow you to delay the call of `continuation` if `f2` becomes asynchronous. It also allows `f1` to choose whether or not to return immediately, and allows for a hypothetical refactored `f3` to accept and pass along `f1`'s continuation or to pass its own (potentially invoking `f1`'s continuation after further processing).

```js
function f1() {
  return f2(a => {
    /* the rest of f1 that consumes a */
    return ...
  });
}

function f2(continuation: (a: TypeOfA) => typeOfF1) {
  if (error) {
    // f1 returns this immediately, and never has its continuation called.
    return ERROR_VALUE;
  }
  // calculate return value
  return continuation(a);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be covered by discussions of tail call optimization?  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization

Comment: @ThomasBitonti Tail call optimization describes how to implement this structure well without overflowing your stack, sure, but I didn't get the sense that this particular question was sufficiently recursive to require it. I deliberately left out performance concerns because [it's complicated in Javascript right now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37224520/1426891) and because we're just talking about the philosophies of control flow here.

Comment: The goal seemed to be, in the calling sequence `f0` calls `f1` calls `f2`, to have `f2` return to `f0`, bypassing the return from `f1`.  Isn't that the basic idea of tail call optimization?

Comment: @ThomasBitonti No and no. First, the goal is not just to let `f2` return to `f0`, it's that `f2` *cancels the rest of `f1`*, which also implies that the call to `f2` is not in a tail position of `f1` (or else there wouldn't be any behavior to cancel). Second, Tail Call Optimization isn't about bypassing behavior, it's just an implementation detail that better allows you to _pretend the computer has infinite memory_ by saying "if the only thing `f1` has left to do is return this `f2` result, let's save memory by forgetting about the call to `f1`. *If `f1` has anything left to do, it's not TCO.*