# call/cc example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scheme, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

Now that [ES6 supports Proper Tail Call](https://webkit.org/blog/6240/ecmascript-6-proper-tail-calls-in-webkit/), and since according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation#Programming_language_support), "In any language which supports closures and proper tail calls, it is possible to write programs in continuation-passing style and manually implement call/cc.", we should be able to properly implement `call/cc` in JavaScript, without using tricks to empty the call stack.
(EDIT: sadly, most web browsers don't support PTC, but we can still use the tricks described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282119))

According to [this article](https://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style), it should look like this:

```js
function callcc (f,cc) { 
  f(function(x,k) { cc(x) },cc)
}
```

As I tried to understand continuations and their usecases, I wanted to implement the second example in [`call/cc`'s page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation#Examples) in JavaScript, but failed:

```lisp
;; [LISTOF X] -> ( -> X u 'you-fell-off-the-end)
(define (generate-one-element-at-a-time lst)
  ;; Both internal functions are closures over lst

  ;; Internal variable/Function which passes the current element in a list
  ;; to its return argument (which is a continuation), or passes an end-of-list marker 
  ;; if no more elements are left. On each step the function name is 
  ;; rebound to a continuation which points back into the function body,
  ;; while return is rebound to whatever continuation the caller specifies.
  (define (control-state return)
    (for-each 
     (lambda (element)
               (set! return (call-with-current-continuation
                              (lambda (resume-here)
                                ;; Grab the current continuation
                               (set! control-state resume-here)
                               (return element))))) ;; (return element) evaluates to next return
     lst)
    (return 'you-fell-off-the-end))
  
  ;; (-> X u 'you-fell-off-the-end)
  ;; This is the actual generator, producing one item from a-list at a time.
  (define (generator)
    (call-with-current-continuation control-state))

  ;; Return the generator 
  generator)

(define generate-digit
  (generate-one-element-at-a-time '(0 1 2)))

(generate-digit) ;; 0
(generate-digit) ;; 1
(generate-digit) ;; 2
(generate-digit) ;; you-fell-off-the-end
```

How would you do it?
Is it even possible?

(EDIT: as explained in the comments, this is not a duplicate of [call/CC with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282119), which is about implementing call/cc in JS; my question is about implementing the Wikipedia example in JS **assuming that call/cc is already implemented** (with or without tricks to empty the call stack), which is not trivial)

---

EDIT: Here is my final working JS implementation, thanks to [that answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318585/6315631), which put me in the right direction:

```js
const callcc = (f,cc) => { f(cc,cc) }

const forEach = (f, lst, cc) => {
  const partialForEach = (f, lst, start, cc) => {
    if (start === lst.length) {
      cc();
    } else {
      f(lst[start], () => partialForEach(f, lst, start+1, cc));
    }
  }
  partialForEach(f, lst, 0, cc)
};

const generate_one_element_a_time = lst => {
  let control_state = (ret) => {
    forEach(
      (element, cc) => {
        callcc(
          (resume_here) => {
            control_state = resume_here
            ret(element)
          },
          c => {
            ret = c
            cc()
          }
        )
      }, 
      lst, 
      () => ret("you-fell-off-the-end")
    )
  }

  let generator = (cc) => {
    callcc(control_state, cc)
  }
  
  return generator
}

const generate_digit = generate_one_element_a_time([0,1,2])

generate_digit(console.log) // 0
generate_digit(console.log) // 1
generate_digit(console.log) // 2
generate_digit(console.log) // you-fell-off-the-end
```

Comment: "*Now that ES6 supports Proper Tail Call*" erm, I think it doesn't. ES6 introduced TCO in the spec but I think V8 abandoned the implementation eventually. Can't remember if FF even started one. EDIT: according [to this article](https://world.hey.com/mgmarlow/what-happened-to-proper-tail-calls-in-javascript-5494c256) only Safari supports TCO. Which is honestly surprising. But none Chrome, Firefox, or Opera support it.

Comment: Relevant (duplicate?): [call/CC with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282119)

Comment: @VLAZ, relevant but not a duplicate: your link's question is about implementing call/cc in JS, my question is about implementing the Wikipedia example in JS assuming that call/cc is already implemented (with or without tricks to empty the call stack)

Comment: @VLAZ, I tested it on Chrome and FF and it seems that you're right  but we can still implement call/cc with the usual tricks to empty the call stack described in your link

Comment: you want to consult daniel friedman's papers.  No need to consult javascript documents to learn how to do it.  it is enough to consult a course of computation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call/CC with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282119/call-cc-with-closures)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `call/cc` so if you rewrite your second example it just won't work since it cannot use your CPS version of `callcc` in JavaScript without the whole program also being rewritten into CPS. `call/cc` in Scheme gives you a way to capture the continuation without writing in continuation passing style, but what Scheme engines do below the belt is to convert the code to CPS. Anyway there is NO CHANCE using the CPS version of `call/cc` with non CPS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
(define (sum-even n)
  (call/cc (lambda (exit)
    (let loop ((n n))
      (cond ((= n 0) 0)
            ((< n 0) (exit 0))
            (else (+ n (loop (- n 2)))))))))

(sum-even 6) ; ==> 12
(sum-even 5) ; ==> 0
```

So the two first uses never actually uses the continuation, but what happens is that you have this in the first `(+ 6 (+ 4 (+ 2 0)))` while in the second we have `(+ 5 (+ 3 (+ 1 (exit 0))))` and the inner expression just kills the rest of the calculations. That is the whole purpose of `call/cc`.

Same in JavaScript:

```
const sumEven = (n) => {
  callCc((exit) => {
    const loop = (n) => {
      if (n === 0) {
        return 0;
      } else if (n < 0) {
        exit(0);
      } else {
        return n + loop(n - 2);
      }
    };
    return loop(n);
  });
};

sumEven(6); // 12 because 6 + 4 + 2 + 0
sumEven(5); // 0 because 5 + 3 + 1 + exit(0)
```

That doesn't work since JavaScipt doesn't provide `callCc`. The second best would be to use rewrite it to CPS:

```js
const callCCK = (f, k) => f((v, ignoredK) => k(v), k);
const sumEvenK = (n, ek) => {
  callCCK((exitK, k) => {
    const loopK = (n, k) => {
      if (n === 0) {
        k(0);
      } else if (n < 0) {
        exitK(0, k);
      } else {
        loopK(n - 2, loopResult => k(n + loopResult));
      }
    };
    loopK(n, k);
  }, ek);
}
sumEvenK(6, v => console.log(v)); // prints 12
sumEvenK(5, v => console.log(v)); // prints 0
```

When your code already is in CPS using callCc isn't really needed since instead we could write it like this:

```js
const sumEvenK = (n, ek) => {
  const loopK = (n, k) => {
    if (n === 0) {
      k(0);
    } else if (n < 0) {
      ek(0);
    } else {
      loopK(n - 2, loopResult => k(n + loopResult));
    }
  };
  loopK(n, ek);
}
sumEvenK(6, v => console.log(v)); // prints 12
sumEvenK(5, v => console.log(v)); // prints 0
```

Since again, the whole reason why we have `call/cc` in Scheme is to get the power of CPS without having to write the tedious CPS.

So there you go. You need to rewrite your `generateOneElementAtATime` into CPS so that it can use the CPS version of your `callcc`. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you: I understood that CPS allowed to write call/cc in a non-first-class-continuation language, but not that if you used CPS, *call/cc become useless*, but to accept your answer I still have one question left: is it *possible* to write the Wikipedia example in JS (in CPS, with or without call/cc) and run it? I can't seem to get the for-each part right… and resuming in the middle of a for-each without coroutines is way more impressive (and maybe useful?) than an emulated return

Comment: I suppose the first step to answer that question would be to translate the for-each part in CPS in Scheme, but I'm not sure how to do that either

Comment: @CidTori Not needed is probably the correct term. Any language that has functions as first class citizens can have code written in CPS style and then `call/cc` is easy to implement in the language itself. My CPS-version with `callCc` of my example works and use `call/cc` when you click Run. The magic of `call/cc` is gone the second we have CPS. CPS Foreach would be like `const forEachK = (fnK, arr, ek) => { const loopK = (i, k) => { if (i === arr.length) { ek(undefined); } else { fnK(arr[i], (ignored) => loopK(i+1, k)); }}; loopK(0, eK);};`

Comment: It looks like this implementation could work indeed! Did you write it just like that or did you get inspiration somewhere? Maybe the Scheme for-each is implemented like that? Anyway, I'll try it ASAP

Comment: @CidTori It's basically the loop in my answer, just generalized. Every developer should try to create a lisp interpreter and then a lisp interpreter/compiler in (not lisp). Also note that the if is open coded in my examples, but you could model it as a function that takes a boolean and calls one of two continuations.

Comment: I edited my question with a working implementation, thanks!  There is still something I can't get right at the end, if you want to take a look

Comment: @CidTori `generate_one_element_a_time` isn't fullly in CPS. It returns instead of calling continuation.  Your code should perhaps look like this: `generate_one_element_a_time([0,1,2],  generate_digit => generate_digit(v=> consoleLogK(v, _=> generate_digit(v=> ...))))`

Comment: Thanks! Full CPS isn’t really needed here but your comment made me realize that I misunderstood how `define` works in Scheme