# Javascript recursive function not returning the result I wanted (tree)

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree-traversal

I am trying to do a recursive function to traversal nodes in a tree

- not binary tree, a parent can have more than 2 children. therefore, for loop or forEach is being used here..
- if node has certain property, return true

```
  traversalNodeTreeWithUrn(root, urn): boolean {
    const nodeList = root;
    for(let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
      const site = nodeList[i].childSite;    
      if(site.urn === urn) {
        return true;      
      } 
      else { 
        return this.traversalNodeTreeWithUrn(site,  urn);
      }
    }
    return false;
```

The problem as recursive, after FOUND return true, it will keep going until all the nodes have been visited and then return final value ( which in my case always return false).

Is there anyway, retain the return true when condition met... or stop the traversal?

Comment: Change your first condition to `if (site.urn === urn || this.traversalNodeTreeWithUrn(site,  urn))`, and get rid of the `else`

Comment: `return` *terminates a function*. So, your `for` works exactly once and it's done. [Does return stop a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714503)

Comment: @RickRunowski  This is not traditional tree, may be I represented it in wrong way.
There is nodeList (like List, array) each of them have multiple childSite(s) and this keep going...  I was going to put 
```const nodeList = root.children```
May be that made more sense...

Comment: @RickRunowski..  Motto already answered my question...  When the condition met (match urn) return true and I was not able to retain the true} since it kept going.  Which Motto's logic work, since with OR || operator, the value (true) will be retain until the end and then return since there is no way to stop recursive function at my knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

**for..of with early exit**

Seems like you're looking for something like -

```js
function nodeHasUrn(node, urn) {
  // does this node match?
  if (node.urn === urn) return true

  for (const child of node.children ?? [])
    // early exit if a child matches
    if (nodeHasUrn(child, urn)) return true
  return false
}
```

This works on a tree shape of -

```js
{
  urn: 1,
  children: [
    { urn: 2 },
    { urn: 3 },
    {
      urn: 4,
      children: [
       { urn: 5 },
       { urn: 6 },
       ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a functioning demo -

```js
function nodeHasUrn(node, urn) {
  if (node.urn === urn) return true
  for (const child of node.children ?? [])
    if (nodeHasUrn(child, urn)) return true
  return false
}

const tree = {
  urn: 1,
  children: [
    { urn: 2 },
    { urn: 3 },
    {
      urn: 4,
      children: [
       { urn: 5 },
       { urn: 6 },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 5)) // true
console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 99)) // false
```

**functional style**

Recursion is a heritage of functional style and so using it with functional style often yields the best results. Consider writing `nodeHasUrn` as a pure functional expression -

```js
const nodeHasUrn = ({ urn, children = [] }, match) =>
  urn === match
    ? true
    : children.some(child =>
        nodeHasUrn(child, match)
      )
```

Which is the same as saying -

```js
const nodeHasUrn = ({ urn, children = [] }, match) =>
  urn === match || children.some(child => nodeHasUrn(child, match))
```

**typescript**

```
type tnode = {
  urn: number,
  children?: Array<tnode>
}

function nodeHasUrn(node: tnode, urn: number): boolean {
  // ...
}
```

Or use a type generic so `urn` can `number` or any other type -

```
type tnode<T> = {
  urn: T,
  children?: Array<tnode<T>>
}

function nodeHasUrn<T>(node: tnode<T>, urn: T): boolean {
  // ...
}
```

**generators**

You named your original method `traversalNodeTreeWithUrn`, which hints you understand the need to traverse the tree. We can separate the `traversal` logic into its own function, resulting in a simplified `nodeHasUrn`, still maintaining the early-exit behavior -

```js
function *traverse(t) {
  yield t
  for (const child of t.children ?? [])
    yield *traverse(child)
}

function nodeHasUrn(t, urn) {
  for (const node of traverse(t))
    if (node.urn == urn)
      return true
  return false
}

const tree = {
  urn: 1,
  children: [
    { urn: 2 },
    { urn: 3 },
    {
      urn: 4,
      children: [
       { urn: 5 },
       { urn: 6 },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 5)) // true
console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 99)) // false
```

**easter eggs**

functional style has a few tricks up its sleeve to blur the lines between it and imperative styles. This approach using `callcc` is distinguished by the `for..of` loop not requiring a nested `if` conditional. Used in this way, `callcc` is the embodiment of "early exit". If you're interested in this technique, you can learn more about `callc` introducted in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024487/633183) -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  try { return f(unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

const nodeHasUrn = (node, match) =>
  callcc(exit =>
    (function loop({ urn, children = [] }) {
      if (urn == match) exit(true) // immediate exit
      children.forEach(loop)
      return false
    })(node)
  )

const tree = {
  urn: 1,
  children: [
    { urn: 2 },
    { urn: 3 },
    {
      urn: 4,
      children: [
       { urn: 5 },
       { urn: 6 },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 5)) // true
console.log(nodeHasUrn(tree, 99)) // false
```

Comment: Very nice.  And if you don't mind a slightly different method of calling, we can simplify further to `const nodeHasUrn = (match) => ({ urn, children = [] }) => urn === match || children.some(nodeHasUrn(match))`, which we'd call like `(nodeHasUrn(5)(tree)`

Comment: thanks Scott! the [η-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#η-reduction) is a nice next-level implementation once the reader understands [curried functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) :D

Comment: @ScottSauyet finding more uses for `callcc` everywhere. I updated the post with you in mind