# Find the parent element of an array by the id of its child

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a JS array that looks like this:

```
const arr = [
    {
        i: "tooltip_119",
        children: [
            {
                i: "text_345",
                children: []
            },
            {
                i: "wraper_375",
                children: [
                    {
                        i: "grid_15",
                        children: []
                    }
                ]             
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        i: "chart_123",
        children: []
    },
    {
        i: "graph_467",
        children: []
    },
]
```

The idea is that such an array can potentially have an infinite number of nestings. And I need a function that, taking the `i` parameter of some element, will return the `i` parameter of its parent (or 0 if the element is at the root and has no parents). An example of how such a function works:

```
console.log(findParent(arr, "grid_15"))  // returns "wraper_375"
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
export function findParent(arr, i) {   // this func has a bug on deep levels
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    const element = arr[j];
    if (element.children && element.children.length > 0) {
      const childElement = element.children.find((e) => e.i === i);
      if (childElement) {
        return element.i;
      } else {
        const parentElement = findParent(element.children, i);
        if (parentElement) {
          return parentElement.i;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my function doesn't work at deeper levels of nesting. I would be grateful for help 
Expected outputs:

```
findParent(arr, "tooltip_119")  // 0
findParent(arr, "chart_123")  // 0
findParent(arr, "graph_467")  // 0
// 0 is returned because these elems do not have parent elem 

findParent(arr, "text_345")  // "tooltip_119"
findParent(arr, "wraper_375")  // "tooltip_119"

findParent(arr, "grid_15")  // "wraper_375"
```

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of inputs / outputs, some that work as expected and some that don't ? That could help targeting the source of the issue.

Comment: @Halibut I edited the question providing outpust

Comment: Can you be more explicit about "doesn't work"? Is there no result? wrong result? throws an error?

Comment: One logical error that is quite evident: when you recurse, you expect your function `findParent` to return a parent element, but it actually returns an id. You can try with simply `return findParent(element.children, i);` in your else block

Comment: My func used to return undefined on deeper levels. But I think the example of Alexander works perfectly

Comment: Yeah, Alexander gave you a fish whereas I was trying to teach you how to fish, as the saying says ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple recursion could be like that:

```js
function findParent(arr, id, parentId = 0) {
  for (const {children, i} of arr) {
    if (i === id){
      return parentId; 
    }
    if (children.length) {
      const childId = findParent(children, id, i);
      if (childId !== null){
        return childId;
      }
    }
  }
  if (parentId === 0) {
    return parentId;
  }
  return null;
}

['wrong_id', 'tooltip_119', 'wraper_375', 'grid_15', 'second_childs_child', 'graph_467']
    .forEach(id => console.log(id, '=>', findParentId(arr, id)));
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
    {
        i: "tooltip_119",
        children: [
            {
                i: "text_345",
                children: []
            },
            {
                i: "wraper_375",
                children: [
                    {
                        i: "grid_15",
                        children: []
                    }
                ]             
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        i: "chart_123",
        children: [{i: 'second_childs_child', children: []}]
    },
    {
        i: "graph_467",
        children: []
    },
]
</script>
```

Another option would be to use a stack to traverse the object:

```js
const findParentId = (arr, id) => {

    let curr = {parentId: 0, arr, j:0};

    stack: while (curr) {

        let { parentId, arr, j } = curr;

        while (j < arr.length) {
            const { children, i } = arr[j];
            curr.j = ++j;
            if (i === id) {
                return parentId;
            }
            if (children.length) {
                curr = { parentId: i, arr: children, j: 0, parent: curr };
                continue stack;
            }
        }

        curr = curr.parent;

    }
};

['wrong_id', 'tooltip_119', 'wraper_375', 'grid_15', 'second_childs_child', 'graph_467']
    .forEach(id => console.log(id, '=>', findParentId(arr, id)));
```

```html
<script>
const arr=[{i:"tooltip_119",children:[{i:"text_345",children:[]},{i:"wraper_375",children:[{i:"grid_15",children:[]}]}]},{i:"chart_123",children:[{i:"second_childs_child",children:[]}]},{i:"graph_467",children:[]},];
</script>
```

And benchmarking:

```
` Chrome/121
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                n=3      |     n=30      |      n=300      |     n=3000    
recursion   1.00x x1m  94 | 1.00x x1m 271 | 1.00x x100k 197 | 1.00x x10k 195
stack       1.41x x1m 133 | 1.42x x1m 385 | 1.39x x100k 274 | 1.34x x10k 262
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk=[{i:"tooltip_119",children:[{i:"text_345",children:[]},{i:"wraper_375",children:[{i:"grid_15",children:[]}]}]},{i:"chart_123",children:[{i:"second_childs_child",children:[]}]},{i:"graph_467",children:[]},];

const $input = [];
const arr = $input;
const ids = ['wrong_id', 'tooltip_119', 'wraper_375', 'grid_15', 'second_childs_child', 'graph_467'];

// @benchmark recursion

const findParentId = (arr, id, parentId = 0) => {
  for(const {children, i} of arr){
    if(i === id){
      return parentId;
    }
    if(children.length){
      const childId = findParentId(children, id, i);
      if(childId){
        return childId;
      }
    }
  }  
};
// @run
ids.map(id => findParentId(arr, id));

// @benchmark stack

const findParentId2 = (arr, id) => {

    let curr = {parentId: 0, arr, j:0};

    stack: while (curr) {

        let { parentId, arr, j } = curr;

        while (j < arr.length) {
            const { children, i } = arr[j];
            curr.j = ++j;
            if (i === id) {
                return parentId;
            }
            if (children.length) {
                curr = { parentId: i, arr: children, j: 0, parent: curr };
                continue stack;
            }
        }

        curr = curr.parent;

    }
};
// @run
ids.map(id => findParentId2(arr, id));

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a unique and efficient solution using a single `for` loop and a single `if` -

```js
function find(nodes, childId) {
  return callcc(function run(exit, parent = null, children = nodes) {
    for (const node of children) {
      if (node.i == childId)
        exit(parent) // short-circuit evaluation
      else
        run(exit, node, node.children)
    }
  })
}

console.log(find(arr, "grid_15"))
```

```js
{
  i: 'wraper_375',
  children: [
    { i: 'grid_15', children: [] },
  ]
}
```

It depends on generic `callcc`, details of implementation in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024487/633183) -

```js
const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  try { return f(unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}
```

If you only want the parent's id, you can `exit(parent.i)` instead.

Comment: Very nice, as always.  See my answer for a BFS version.

Answer (score 2):

The useful answers from Alexander Nenashev and Aniket Raj, as well as the very interesting continuation-based one from Mulan, all do depth-first traversals to find the first match.

Another technique would be to do a breadth-first traversal.  Here we have one built on a more generic parent-finding-by-predicate function, which itself is built atop a generic node-finding-by-predicate function.

```js
const findNode = (pred) => (xs = []) => 
  xs.find(pred) || findNode(pred)(xs.flatMap(x => x.children || []))

const findParent = (pred = () => false) =>
  findNode(({children = []}) => children.some(pred))

const findParentIdById = (xs = [], id = '', p = findParent((x) => x.i == id)(xs)) => 
  p && p.i

const arr = [{i: "tooltip_119", children: [{i: "text_345", children: []}, {i: "wraper_375", children: [{i: "grid_15", children: []}]}]}, {i: "chart_123", children: []}, {i: "graph_467", children: []}]

console.log(findParentIdById(arr, 'grid_15'))
```

Here `findNode` and `findParent` are reusable utility functions which accept a predicate and return function which accept an array.  **`findNode`** recursively finds the first node which matches the predicate, and if none does, the first of their `children` which matches it, and if none does, the first of their grand-`children`, and so on.  **`findParent`** takes a predicate and calls `findNode` with a predicate which checks if any of the node's `children` match the original one.

**`findParentById`** simply calls `findParent` with a predicate which tests if the `i` property matches the value supplied.

Answer (score 1):

For deep nesting, this data representation might not be the most effective. You may consider restructuring it and make your life easier.

Especially if you would have to call this `findParent` function frequently, it might be worth migrating your array to a different structure, like so:

```js
const arr = [
    { i: "tooltip_119", parent: null },
    { i: "text_345", parent: "tooltip_119" },
    { i: "wraper_375", parent: "tooltip_119" },
    { i: "grid_15", parent: "wraper_375" },
    { i: "chart_123", parent: null },
    { i: "graph_467", parent: null }
];
```

Then it's just a lookup as compared to a search: `O(1)` instead of `O(N)` complexity. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have thought of it, but this sollution can not be implemented in my project since i use React-grid-layout and i need my array to be as it is in the example.  But it's still an interesting concept

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working example:**
It returns the **parent node** (with all of its details) of found children element.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    i: "tooltip_119",
    children: [
      {
        i: "text_345",
        children: [],
      },
      {
        i: "wraper_375",
        children: [
          {
            i: "grid_15",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    i: "chart_123",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    i: "graph_467",
    children: [
      {
        i: "chart_1222",
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];

//solution: 

function finder(arr, key, parent) {
  for (let elem of arr) {
    if (elem.i == key) return parent;
    if (elem.children.length > 0) {
      let foundParentNode = finder(elem.children, key, elem);
      if (foundParentNode) return foundParentNode;
    }
  }
}

let result = finder(arr, "grid_15", {});

console.log(result.i);
```