# Is it possible to assign the result of a block to a variable?

Tags: javascript

A code block like this yields a value in chrome console and repl

```
{
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  x;
}
```

[image: picture of the code in the console]

Is it possible to assign the result of a block to a variable?

This will throw an error because `{}` is interpreted as an object here

```
const a = {
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  x;
}
```

Comment: in javascript blocks are not expressions. so no. otherwise they would be objects. you could use an iife

Comment: Is there any reason to use blocks apart from confusing other devs then?

Comment: Consider using a function.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript does not have block expressions as some other languages do. As you noted, it becomes an object/error.

What you could do is use an IIFE and return a value from it.

```js
const a = (() => {
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  return x;
})();

console.log(a)
```

The point of blocks has greatly increased now that `const` and `let` have much more robust scoping rules over `var`. It also would be useful with the new `using` support as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a function, or similar.

```
const fn = () => {
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  return x;
}

const a = fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like eval works (I know that eval is evil)

```js
const a = eval(`{
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  x;
}`)

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think anyone can enjoy this simple `call` function. You could rename it `block` if it helps you to think in those terms -

```js
const call = (f, ...args) => f(...args)

console.log(call(() => {
  let x = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    x *= i;
  }
  return(x);
}))

console.log(call(
  function recur(x) {
    return x == 0 ? 1 : x * recur(x - 1)
  },
  10
))

console.log(call(
  function recur(x, prod) {
    return x == 0 ? prod : recur(x - 1, prod * x)
  },
  10,
  1
))
```

When using `call` with recursive function, often we need a way to exit the function if a result can be determined early. The `call` function can be combined with `callcc`, or [call with current continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation), originally demonstrated in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72024487/633183) -

```js
const call = (f, ...args) => f(...args)

const callcc = f => {
  const box = Symbol()
  try { return f(unbox => { throw {box, unbox} }) }
  catch (e) { if (e?.box == box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}

const product = numbers =>
  callcc(exit => call(function recur(x) {
    if (x.length == 0) return 1
    if (x[0] == 0) exit(0) // immediate exit
    return x[0] * recur(x.slice(1))
  }, numbers))

console.log(product([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])) // 3628800
console.log(product([1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,10])) // 0
  
const find = (tree, query) =>
  callcc(exit => call(function recur(t) {
    if (t == null) return
    if (t[0] == query) exit(t) // immediate exit!
    for (const child of t[1] ?? []) recur(child)
  }, tree))
  
const mytree =
  [0, [[1], [2, [[3], [4, [[5]]]]]]]
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(find(mytree, 3))) // [3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(find(mytree, 4))) // [4,[[5]]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(find(mytree, 9))) // undefined
```

Both functions can be made type-safe -

```
function call<R>(f: () => R): R
function call<A, R>(f: (a: A) => R, a: A): R
function call<A, B, R>(f: (a: A, b: B) => R, a: A, b: B): R
function call<A, B, C, R>(f: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => R, a: A, b: B, c: C): R
function call<A, B, C, D, R>(f: (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => R, a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): R
function call<A, B, C, D, E, R>(f: (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => R, a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E): R
function call<R>(f: (...args: unknown[]) => R, ...args: unknown[]): R {
  return f(...args) as R
}
```

```
function callcc<R>(f: (exit: (value: R) => R) => R): R {
  class Box { public unbox: R; constructor(v: R) { this.unbox = v  } }
  try { return f(value => { throw new Box(value) }) }
  catch (e) { if (e instanceof Box) return e.unbox; throw e  }
}
```

Comment: why?! this seems like so much overkill...

Comment: maybe you can be more specific? the question asks how to evaluate a "block" of code as an expression or value. `call` and `callcc` are well-defined, type-safe functions to create such blocks; simple, with arguments, recursive, and with continuation control examples are provided, each demonstrating correct behavior. these simple forms allow for complex and sophisticated block compositions. i'm sorry if the examples are lost on you.

Comment: Though technically correct and fascinating from a literal standpoint it is very difficult to reason about at a glance. I apploud the effort and the academics of this solution. I can’t see myself using it often as returning to this code after a break would immediately generate a “WTF was I doing?” moment. Sadly, the solution which also includes human readability as a requirement would be to do this long hand without utility functions. I would not mind seeing something like this in the stdlib. The unfamiliarity of the solution though would slow most down and inspire rewrites.